# Problem storing string in 2D array inside a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have a char `array` which contains `n` number of strings. I am trying to save all of them to another 2d array inside a linked list. I don't get any error message, but the program crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: I won't add the section where I add strings to `array`, because it is long. The problem isn't there, because if I should print them, they all appear.

```
typedef struct userInfo {
    char info[40][256];
} userInfo;
typedef struct List {
    userInfo data;
    struct List *next;
} List;

char array[lines + 2][256];

List *head = NULL;
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
   strcpy(head->data.info[i], array[i]);
   printf("%s", head->data.info[i]);
}
head->next = NULL;
```

Comment: You are dereferencing a null pointer. Need I say more?

Comment: Oh, thank you. Didn't see it.